# Cannot edit "Register with Test Controller"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Test Agent is installed on a server. When I try to Configure the Test Agent, I am not able to edit the options in the "Register with Test Controller" part. This is checked but completely grayed out. I want to change the test Controller port but can't.

Any suggestions? I am admin.

[screenshot of Test Agent configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ4bD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your Test Agent is part of an Environment(you can see that in your screen shot). SO if you want to change the test controller you will have to do it through "Microsoft Test Manager"(MTM). Here are the steps.
- Open MTM
- Go to "Lab Center" (its a drop down on top)
- When you select lab center, you can see "Environments" Tab. It will list all the test agents.
- Locate your test agent(by name). Open it.
- Go to Advanced Tab and change your test controller there.
- Proceed to next steps to finish the step.